# How to login to database through ssh server in r

Tags: r, dplyr, ssh, dbplyr

I want to login to a database but I need to have access login in through the server and the only way is to log in via `ssh`

I was able to establish a connection on the server using ssh from the package `ssh` in r

see below

```
ssh = ssh::ssh_connect("y_og_i@1xx.7x.xx1.8x")
```

after this a window will pop up in the Rstudio requesting for the server password which I input the password, then I got this response below that it is connected, please check below

```
print(ssh)
<ssh session>
connected: y_og_i@1xx.7x.xx1.8x:21
server: a:3:87:6d:a3:9c:06:xa:36:31:4b:8b:a8:8d04:f6:09:ar
```

Now that I have established a connection to the server based on the above description,
I still cannot log in to the database

See the database details below

```
con <- dbConnect(
  RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
  host = "1xx.7x.xx1.8x",
  port = 21,
  dbname = "chMerchants",
  user = "xxxxx",
  password = "dgghgddcscrrhxxxxxxx")
```

I got this error below

```
Error: Failed to connect: Lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 2
```

Is there anything wrong with the ssh setup why is it now allowing me to have access to the db
or is it that my configuration is wrong or something, someone should assist me

Comment: I tried `ssh::ssh_connect()`, but every time I connected, it would drop off once I had established a connection. Can you set up a SSH tunnel outside R (perhaps using the terminal inside RStudio)? This may be the more robust approach.

Answer (score 1):

Once check the port number, as port 21 is usually used for FTP.
Here 3306 port is being used.
`

```
ssh <- ssh::ssh_connect("y_og_i@1xx.7x.xx1.8x")
db_port <- 3306
tunnel <- ssh::ssh_tunnel(ssh, tunnel_port = db_port, target = "localhost", target_port = db_port)
con <- dbConnect(
  RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
  host = "localhost",
  port = tunnel$local_port,
  dbname = "chMerchants",
  user = "xxxxx",
  password = "dgghgddcscrrhxxxxxxx")
```

`

Comment: This the error message i received 
`tunnel <- ssh::ssh_tunnel(ssh, tunnel_port = db_port, target = "localhost", target_port = db_port)
Error in ssh::ssh_tunnel(ssh, tunnel_port = db_port, target = "localhost",  : 
  unused arguments (tunnel_port = db_port, target_port = db_port)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).